# Using model's prediction score as movement quality evaluator

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification

Let's take the task of evaluating very short dance movements (phrases) using sensor data (accelerometer and gyro data from iPhone sensors) as an example. If the model's confidence is 100% on a particular dance phrase, it does not necessarily follow that the user performed this movement phrase perfectly.

Given this task that consists of very short movements (1-2sec), given that a very high-quality dataset (sensor data) is under disposal, given that the model has very high accuracy in classifying these movement phrases (actions) would it be fair to assume that this action classifier can also serve as a movement evaluator?

For example, we can set a threshold of 50% and evaluate the movements based on the model's confidence, i.e. if the model is 40% confident that this movement (we know the ground-truth beforehand) is X we say that the user didn't perform the movement correctly but if the model has a 90% confidence we say that the movement was performed correctly. In other words, we give feedback to the user about his performance based on the model's confidence.

Or it still doesn't matter and we can't simply draw the conclusion that a robust action classifier can be treated as a potential action evaluator?

Alternatively, how much sense it would (theoretically) make if I feed certain data qualitative characteristics, such as the `25th`, `50th`, and `75th` percentile (certain spikes at these points make up for the quality of my kind of data) as well as the mean and S.D. for each sensor as features to an attention model reasoning that, since I feed these as input features to the model, the classifier's prediction might now have been slightly nudged to an evaluator's prediction?

Comment: You said it yourself; "it does not necessarily follow that the user performed this movement phrase perfectly." The feature set that your model extracts from the phrases are not necessarily good candidates for evaluating the quality of very short movements (sub-actions, if you will), unless your model is trained to keep the consistency within these very short movements.

Comment: Any (general) pointers on how the model is trained to keep this consistency?

Comment: You would need to address this concern in the loss function. And the way you can accomplish that pretty much completely depends on your dataset. You have mentioned that you have a high quality dataset so I assume that you might have enough granularity in your data to measure the quality of your sub-actions. These measurements could be integrated into the general loss function as an auxiliary loss so that your model can be optimized towards prioritizing the quality of sub-actions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Do you happen to know some implementation of this idea in some context that you could refer me to?

Comment: You're most welcome. I will come up with a proper answer, if you find the idea useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said it yourself; "it does not necessarily follow that the user performed this movement phrase perfectly." The feature set that your model extracts from the phrases are not necessarily good candidates for evaluating the quality of very short movements (sub-actions, if you will), unless your model is trained to keep the consistency within these very short movements.

You could address this concern in the loss function. And the way you can accomplish that pretty much completely depends on your dataset. You have mentioned that you have a high quality dataset so I assume that you might have enough granularity in your data to measure the quality of your sub-actions. These measurements could be integrated into the general loss function as an auxiliary loss so that your model can be optimized towards prioritizing the quality of sub-actions.

Here are some studies [(1)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/8758034)[(2)](https://github.com/Ling-Bao/ACSCP_cGAN) that explore similar possibilities for Crowd Density Estimation task.

Comment: Thanks for your pointers! 

One more question though: how much sense do you think it (theoretically) makes if I feed certain data qualitative characteristics, such as the 25th, 50th, and 75 percentile (certain spikes at these points make up for the quality of my kind of data) as well as the mean and S.D. for each sensor as features to an attention model reasoning that since I feed these as input features to the model, the classifier's prediction might now have been slightly nudged to an evaluator's prediction?

Comment: Hard to say, since I do not know if those data qualitative characteristics can represent patterns that you expect to be in your input. To design the attention structure, I would rather find the features that fire up to the correct execution of very short movements at early layers of the network but diminish through the higher layers. This might as well be input characteristics, as you have suggested, cant say more without seeing the data.